# How use vue-router and httpVueLoader in neutralinojs project?

Tags: neutralinojs

Neutralinojs is really good thing. I trying write app using vue and neutralino. Vue without router working good. But if I add vue-router and httpVueLoader to project my app is not working.

I do following: write vue app and locate it in *app* folder of neutralino project. All files exclude *index.html* located in *app/assets*

Next I run *http-server app/* and view my app in browser. All right, no errors in console. Next I run *./neutralino* They open the browser, **show my app page without a router-vue components** and I see error in console:

[image]

It's look like neutralino client can't receive vue component *c1.vue* from server

You can [download my neutralino project](https://ufile.io/hwaq3vae) for reproduce this error